# Попробовал собрать проект ownCloud в Ubuntu в среде Qt 5.5. Ошибку выдавал. Как можно решить?

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, cmake

Может кто-то столкнулся. В windows пробовал собрать, но cmake не создал ownCloud.rc. Так и не получилось в windows. Потом пробовал в линуксе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вывод явно намекает, что нет либы GL. в убунте оно скорее всего поставляется с mesa-dev или чем то подобным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не найден файл `GL/gl.h`.

скорее всего, он имеется в каком-нибудь из репозиторных пакетов.

поиск файла в репозиторных пакетах можно произвести программой `apt-file` (если пакет `apt-file` не установлен, его надо установить, а затем обновить список, выполнив команду `$ sudo apt-file update`). ориентировочный вывод (в вашей системе может отличаться):

```
$ apt-file search GL/gl.h
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/system/include/GL/gl.h
libogre-1.9-dev: /usr/include/OGRE/RenderSystems/GL/GL/gl.h
libroot-core5.34: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/root5.34/cint/include/GL/gl.h
mesa-common-dev: /usr/include/GL/gl.h
mingw-w64-common: /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/GL/gl.h
mingw-w64-i686-dev: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/GL/gl.h
mingw-w64-x86-64-dev: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GL/gl.h
```

логичнее всего выглядит файл `/usr/include/GL/gl.h` из пакета `mesa-common-dev`, который и следует установить.

#### не-ascii-символы в пути

> /home/asus/**загрузки**/client-master-build/cmakefiles/cmakeoutput.log

это «бомба замедленного действия», с большой вероятностью приводящая к абсолютно неочевидным ошибкам сборки. лучше избавиться от этого до того, как вы столкнётесь с проблемами: используйте при сборке каталоги, в полных путях которых содержатся **только печатные ascii-символы**.

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил про русские символы в пути. Наверняка позже вылезет.

Comment: @donRumata, да, стоит про такое упомянуть. дополнил ответ.